# kubectl - error: You must be logged in to the server on bare-metal

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I created the csr and approved it -

```
$ kubectl get csr
NAME        AGE   REQUESTOR          CONDITION
parth-csr   28m   kubernetes-admin   Approved,Issued
```

Created the certificate using kubectl only with username parth and group devs

```
        Issuer: CN=kubernetes
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 16 18:51:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Dec 15 18:51:00 2020 GMT
        Subject: O=devs, CN=parth
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
```

Here, I want to do the authentication on the basis of group - devs.

Clusterrole.yaml is as follows -

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: devs
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes", "pods", "secrets", "pods", "pods/log", "configmaps", "services", "endpoints", "deployments", "jobs", "crontabs"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Clusterrolebinding.yaml as

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: devs-clusterrolebinding
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: devs # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: devs
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Kubeconfig file is as follows -

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    server: https://XX.XX.XX.XX:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: parth
  name: dev
current-context: "dev"
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: parth
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/access-credentials/parth/parth.crt
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/access-credentials/parth/parth.key
```

As I want to do auth using group only, I am getting the following error -

```
$ kubectl get nodes
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

I am running k8s on bare-metal.
Group based auth reference from offical docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding

Answer (score 1):

I see you have given permission to groups and not to a user . In that case you need to use impersonation as group

```
kubectl get nodes --as-group=devs
```

Comment: I am getting the following error now -
`
$ kubectl get nodes --as-group=devs
error: requesting groups or user-extra for  without impersonating a user
`

Comment: @ParthWadhwa Have you tried adding a ClusterRoleBinding that binds subject of kind User for your user? See if that works?

Comment: `
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: parth-clusterrolebinding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: parth # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: devs
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
`
@Shambu
Even after creating the clusterrolebinding that binds subject of kind User i am facing the same problem.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this: adding `--as-group=devs --as=nonexistentuser` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After manually signing the certificate using apiserver ca, it got fixed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did this?